# Why is there a line break in the middle of my text?

Tags: css

I feel dumb for asking this but, I can't figure out why there is a line break.  All three links should be on the same line.

HTML

```
<div class="mailcontainerheader"><a href="/messages/inbox/"><div class="highlighted">Inbox</div></a> | <a href="/messages/outbox/">Sent</a> | <a href="/messages/trash/">Trash</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.mailcontainerheader .highlighted {
  color:red;
  display:block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYxGaJ

So I guess specifically my question is how do I apply styling to one of the links inside the parent div without that mysterious line break?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a div inside your first `<a>` tag.

Divs are blocks, which cannot share the same line with any other element. Furthermore, you even set your `.highlighted` to be a block element.

You can change that by making them inline-blocks:

```
a div
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

If you're only trying to highlight the specific `<a>` tag, you should just apply the CSS styles to the `<a>`, rather than inserting a whole extra element.

Why not just do this:

```
<div class="mailcontainerheader">
    <a class="highlighted" href="/messages/inbox/">Inbox</a> | 
    <a href="/messages/outbox/">Sent</a> | 
    <a href="/messages/trash/">Trash</a>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlighted
{
    color: red;
}
```

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEvYbY)

Answer (score 1):

```
.mailcontainerheader a{ 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Add this to your CSS